# What's the best way to get from Gare Du Nord to Viking Cruise ship?

Tags: transit, paris

What's the best way to get from Gare Du Nord to Quai Maurice Berteaux 78230 Le Pecq if we want the fewest transfers for the cheapest price?

Comment: "Best" is impossibly imprecise. Quickest? Cheapest? Easiest? Fewest transfers?

Comment: fewest transfers, cheapeast

Comment: Better! We expect that folks who ask questions will have conducted some research on their own...there is a whole internet out there. You might start yours at rome2rio.com.

Comment: One of the French railway sites or even google maps, (rather than Rome2Rio) I'd say.

Comment: How many are you? How much luggage do you have?

Comment: Also, what date and at what time do you need to be there?

Answer (score 6):

The cheapest way will be to use the RER taking about an hour, but this means you will have to transfer lines. The ticket costs under €5 and you use it for both trains. You can buy these at the machines in any station.

From Gare Du Nord you take either the B or D line to Châtelet - Les Halles. (The train will read as GARE DE CORBEIL, and you get off on the first stop)

From Châtelet - Les Halles you then change trains and take the A line to Le Vésinet - Le Pecq. (The train will read GARE DE ST GERMAIN and you'll ride it 10 stops)

From there you then have a [16 minute walk](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Gare+du+Nord,+75010+Paris,+France/Quai+Maurice+Berteaux,+78230+Le+Pecq,+France/@48.881939,2.161866,12z/am=t/data=!4m16!4m15!1m5!1m1!1s0x47e66e6e1faec3db:0xeb0747ded395615c!2m2!1d2.3552167!2d48.8809397!1m5!1m1!1s0x47e66286b0472fad:0x4b3092df8d70dca4!2m2!1d2.106979!2d48.896818!2m1!4e2!3e3) to board the ship. 
Alternatively it will take around 45 minutes in a taxi, but will cost considerably more.

Answer (score 5):

**Fewest transfers** = taxi, from Gare du Nord directly to the quay (no transfers)

**Cheapest** = Metro, RER, then walk to the quay (two transfers, then a long walk)

Perhaps **a combo** would appeal:

Metro, then train to Le Pecq, then taxi from the train station to the quay.

Your choice!

Answer (score 3):

This is a map of [line B](https://parisbytrain.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/07/rer_b_train_line_map.pdf), you want to take the train eastbound from *Gare Du Nord* one stop to *Châtelet-les Halles*.

Then you want to change to the 
[A line](https://parisbytrain.-content/uploads/2008/07/rer_a_train_line_map.pdf) and take the train westbound to *Saint Germain-en-Laye*.

From there according to Google Maps it is a 19-minute walk:

[image]

From the station walk to *GARE DE ST-GERMAIN-EN-LAYE* and take the line 01 bus towards *GARE DE RUEIL-MALMAISON* and get off at *PONT DU PECQ*, from there it is only a 1 minute walk, the route is shown below:

[image]

Similar journeys can be planned on [this site](https://www.ratp.fr/en/itineraires).

Answer (score 2):

Take the RER E to Hausmann St-Lazare (one stop), then change for the RER A towards St Germain en Laye and get off at Le Vésinet Le Pecq. From there, walk 1.5 km and the ship is across the river Seine.

Answer (score -2):

A taxi.

Might be costlier than a metro but beats having to do with luggage and all the walking.

Comment: So much costlier that I see it as not answering the questions added details, cheapest.